# Loop in js for specific value without if

Tags: javascript, lodash

I use the following code which is working great but I wonder if in JS there is a way to avoid the if and to do it inside the loop, I want to use also lodash if it helps

```
for (provider in config.providers[0]) {
    if (provider === "save") {
        ....
```

Comment: `if (config.providers[0].save) { ... }`?

Comment: `var provider=0; while(config.providers[0][provider] !== "save") provider++;`

Comment: @vinayakj that will terminate the loop once `provider === 'save'`. I believe OP is looking for a filter-like iteration.

Comment: @robertklep- Currenlty the save is hardcoded but what will you do if its coming from other varible,Thanks!

Comment: @initialxy I termined loop, but Op can surely insert statements there

Comment: @AlBundy can you show us an example of `config.providers[0]`? It seems everyone thinks that it's an array, but looking at your example code, it's an object.

Comment: @robertklep good catch! However lodash/underscore's filter and each will work on iterating object properties too.

Comment: @initialxy I know, but the key is passed as second argument, not first, which is what I'm seeing being used in most answers :-) (`provider` in the question's code is the key)

Comment: @robertklep Assume correctness of OP's code. He's actually comparing `'save'` to the **value** of each of the properties instead of looking up a property named save. Therefore `config.providers[0].save` is inconsistent with OP's logic. We still need to iterate all properties in this object and compare their values.

Comment: @initialxy `for .. in ..` iterates over enumerable _properties_, so `provider` is a property, not a value.

Comment: @robertklep oops yap you are right. My bad. I shall upvote your answer. I'd actually argue that your assumption is more correct, since the correct way to iterate array in ECMAScript 6 is `for ... of ...` while `for ... in ...` is intended for iterating keys in an object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can chain calls together using [`_.chain`](https://lodash.com/docs#chain), [filter](https://lodash.com/docs#filter) by a value, and then use [each](https://lodash.com/docs#forEach) to call a function for each filtered result. However, you have to add a final `.value()` call at the end for it to evaluate the expression you just built.

I'd argue that for short, simple conditional blocks, an `if` statement is easier and more readable. I'd use lodash- and more specifically chaining- if you are combining multiple operations or performing sophisticated filtering, sorting, etc. over an object or collection.

```js
var providers = ['hello', 'world', 'save'];

_.chain(providers)
  .filter(function(provider) {
    return provider === 'save';
  }).each(function(p) {
    document.write(p); // your code here
  }).value();
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/3.8.0/lodash.js"></script>
```

Edit: My mistake; `filter` does not have an overload where you can just supply a literal value. If you want to do literal value checking you have to supply a function as in my amended answer above.

Comment: Don't shoot downvotes from the dark (just watched someone downvote a few of the answers just now); it doesn't help anybody. If you don't like the answer, please comment why.

Comment: Thanks! I try it but It doesnt go to the next line any idea why?where you put the do someting...

Comment: I didn't downvote but here is a thing I noticed. `filter` takes a function not a value. I just tested this and unfortunately it won't work. Try `.filter(function(p) {return p === 'save'})` or if you really like to live on the edge, `.filter(p => p === 'save')`

Comment: @initialxy Agh, you're right. Some of the methods like `filter` will check to see if the value literally matches, but in this case, if you provide a string `filter` will check if the object has a property matching the string with a true-ish value. Sometimes lodash is a little inconsistent.

Comment: @AlBundy Sorry. I made a mess of my answer. I should know better than to answer questions at 4 AM after drinking beers. See my amended answer and provided example.

Comment: Thanks :) can you please say where I should put my code inside this loop ?

Comment: @AlBundy in the `each` (I added a comment)

Answer (score 1):

Basically, you are testing to see if `config.providers[0]`, which is an object, contains a property called `save` (or some other dynamic value, I'm using a variable called `provider` to store that value in my example code below).

You can use this instead of using a `for .. in ..` loop:

```
var provider = 'save';
if (config.providers[0][provider] !== undefined) {
  ...
}
```

Or using @initialxy's (better!) suggestion:

```
if (provider in config.providers[0]) {
  ...
}
```

Comment: I'd argue that this is more likely the correct answer, since in ECMAScript 6, `for ... in ...` is intended for iterating keys in an object, while `for ... of ...` is intended for iterating array. On a different note, may I suggest something like `if ('save' in config.providers[0])`?

Comment: @initialxy I hardly ever use `in`, I should use it more!

Answer (score 1):

I'd argue that what you have there is pretty good, clean and readable, but since you mentioned lodash, I will give it a try.

```
_.each(_.filter(config.providers[0], p => p === 'save'), p => {
    // Do something with p
    ...
});
```

Note that the arrow function/lambda of ECMAScript 6 doesn't come to Chrome until version 45.

Answer (score 0):

How about:

```
for (provider in config.providers[0].filter(function(a) {return a === "save"}) {
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Strategy, you are looking for some kind of strategy pattern as,

> Currenlty the save is hardcoded but what will you do if its coming from other varible – Al Bundy

```js
var actions = {
  save: function() {
    alert('saved with args: ' + JSON.stringify(arguments))
  },
  delete: function() {
    alert('deleted')
  },
  default: function() {
    alert('action not supported')
  }
}

var config = {
  providers: [{
    'save': function() {
      return {
        action: 'save',
        args: 'some arguments' 
      }
    },
    notSupported: function() {}
  }]
}

for (provider in config.providers[0]) {
  (actions[provider] || actions['default'])(config.providers[0][provider]())
}
```

Push „Run code snippet” button will shows two pop-ups - be carefull

Answer (score 0):

It is not clearly stated by the original poster whether the desired output
should be a *single* **save** - or an array containing *all* occurrences of
**save**.

This answer shows a solution to the latter case.

```js
const providers = ['save', 'hello', 'world', 'save'];
const saves = [];
_.forEach(_.filter(providers, elem => { return elem==='save' }),
  provider => { saves.push(provider); });
console.log(saves);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.19/lodash.js"></script>
```